# On Bind I see a strange error logging

Tags: logs, bind, bind9

Today I see on my bind9 log directory a lot of log (empty!) files.

```
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1             querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2          update-debug.log.3.1.1.1.1.2
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1               querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2.1        update-debug.log.3.1.1.1.1.2.1
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.1             querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.2            update-debug.log.3.1.1.1.2
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1           querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.2.1          update-debug.log.3.1.1.1.2.1
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1         querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.2              update-debug.log.3.1.1.2
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2             querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1.2.1            update-debug.log.3.1.1.2.1
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.1           querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.2            update-debug.log.3.1.2
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2               querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.1              update-debug.log.3.1.2.1
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1             querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.3              update-debug.log.3.2
querylog.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2             querylog.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1.3.1            update-debug.log.3.2.1
```

the list is incomplete, there are over 7000 files.
This is the configuration of logging on named.conf

```
logging {
     channel update_debug {
          file "/var/log/update-debug.log";
          severity  debug 1;
          print-category yes;
          print-severity yes;
          print-time     yes;
     };
     channel security_info    {
          file "/var/log/named-auth.info";
          severity  info;
          print-category yes;
          print-severity yes;
          print-time     yes;
     };
     channel querylog { 
          file "/var/log/querylog";
          severity debug 1;
          print-category yes;
          print-severity yes;
          print-time     yes;
};
     category update { update_debug; };
     category security { security_info; };
     category queries { querylog; };
};
```

How to avoid this fragmentation?

Comment: Could this be an ill-witten `logrotate` rule? If you use `logrotate`, can you add the relevant part of its configuration here? An `ls -lc` of those log files would also give some hints on how they were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found using [this configuration](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01526)